# Unable to access template objects using boost::apply_visitor

Tags: c++, boost, stdmap, boost-variant

I am learning about boost::variant and accessing its members using apply_visitor. So, I wrote the following example.
I have pointers to templated objects as my class members. I would like to access them using apply_visitor.

```
//Example program
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>
#include <boost/variant.hpp>
#include <boost/any.hpp>

class A {
    template<size_t dim>
    struct C : boost::static_visitor<C<dim> *>{
        int x;
        C() {
          x = dim;
        }
        template <size_t t>
        C<t> * operator()(C<t> *s) const {
          std::cout<<s->x<<std::endl;
          return s;
        }
    };
 public: 
    C<1>* Aasd;
    C<2>* Bbsd;
    std::map<std::string, boost::variant<C<2> *, C<1> * > > matrices;    

    A() {
        Aasd = new C<1>;
        Bbsd = new C<2>;
    matrices.insert(std::make_pair("Bb", Bbsd));

   boost::apply_visitor(C<2>(), matrices["Bb"]);
   //   boost::apply_visitor(C<1>(), matrices["Aa"]);
   }

    ~A() {
     delete Aasd;
     delete Bbsd;
    }        
};

int main()
{    
  A a;
  return 0;
}
```

The error that I get from compiling the above is

```
In file included from /usr/include/boost/variant.hpp:17:0,
                 from 8:
/usr/include/boost/variant/variant.hpp: In instantiation of 'boost::detail::variant::invoke_visitor<Visitor>::result_type boost::detail::variant::invoke_visitor<Visitor>::internal_visit(T&, int) [with T = A::C<1ul>*; Visitor = const A::C<2ul>; boost::detail::variant::invoke_visitor<Visitor>::result_type = A::C<2ul>*]':
/usr/include/boost/variant/detail/visitation_impl.hpp:130:9:   required from 'typename Visitor::result_type boost::detail::variant::visitation_impl_invoke_impl(int, Visitor&, VoidPtrCV, T*, mpl_::true_) [with Visitor = boost::detail::variant::invoke_visitor<const A::C<2ul> >; VoidPtrCV = void*; T = A::C<1ul>*; typename Visitor::result_type = A::C<2ul>*; mpl_::true_ = mpl_::bool_<true>]'
/usr/include/boost/variant/detail/visitation_impl.hpp:173:9:   required from 'typename Visitor::result_type boost::detail::variant::visitation_impl_invoke(int, Visitor&, VoidPtrCV, T*, NoBackupFlag, int) [with Visitor = boost::detail::variant::invoke_visitor<const A::C<2ul> >; VoidPtrCV = void*; T = A::C<1ul>*; NoBackupFlag = boost::variant<A::C<2ul>*, A::C<1ul>*>::has_fallback_type_; typename Visitor::result_type = A::C<2ul>*]'
/usr/include/boost/variant/detail/visitation_impl.hpp:256:5:   required from 'typename Visitor::result_type boost::detail::variant::visitation_impl(int, int, Visitor&, VoidPtrCV, mpl_::false_, NoBackupFlag, Which*, step0*) [with Which = mpl_::int_<0>; step0 = boost::detail::variant::visitation_impl_step<boost::mpl::l_iter<boost::mpl::l_item<mpl_::long_<2l>, A::C<2ul>*, boost::mpl::l_item<mpl_::long_<1l>, A::C<1ul>*, boost::mpl::l_end> > >, boost::mpl::l_iter<boost::mpl::l_end> >; Visitor = boost::detail::variant::invoke_visitor<const A::C<2ul> >; VoidPtrCV = void*; NoBackupFlag = boost::variant<A::C<2ul>*, A::C<1ul>*>::has_fallback_type_; typename Visitor::result_type = A::C<2ul>*; mpl_::false_ = mpl_::bool_<false>]'
/usr/include/boost/variant/variant.hpp:2367:13:   required from 'static typename Visitor::result_type boost::variant<T0, T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8, T9, T10, T11, T12, T13, T14, T15, T16, T17, T18, T19>::internal_apply_visitor_impl(int, int, Visitor&, VoidPtrCV) [with Visitor = boost::detail::variant::invoke_visitor<const A::C<2ul> >; VoidPtrCV = void*; T0_ = A::C<2ul>*; T1 = A::C<1ul>*; T2 = boost::detail::variant::void_; T3 = boost::detail::variant::void_; T4 = boost::detail::variant::void_; T5 = boost::detail::variant::void_; T6 = boost::detail::variant::void_; T7 = boost::detail::variant::void_; T8 = boost::detail::variant::void_; T9 = boost::detail::variant::void_; T10 = boost::detail::variant::void_; T11 = boost::detail::variant::void_; T12 = boost::detail::variant::void_; T13 = boost::detail::variant::void_; T14 = boost::detail::variant::void_; T15 = boost::detail::variant::void_; T16 = boost::detail::variant::void_; T17 = boost::detail::variant::void_; T18 = boost::detail::variant::void_; T19 = boost::detail::variant::void_; typename Visitor::result_type = A::C<2ul>*]'
/usr/include/boost/variant/variant.hpp:2378:13:   required from 'typename Visitor::result_type boost::variant<T0, T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8, T9, T10, T11, T12, T13, T14, T15, T16, T17, T18, T19>::internal_apply_visitor(Visitor&) [with Visitor = boost::detail::variant::invoke_visitor<const A::C<2ul> >; T0_ = A::C<2ul>*; T1 = A::C<1ul>*; T2 = boost::detail::variant::void_; T3 = boost::detail::variant::void_; T4 = boost::detail::variant::void_; T5 = boost::detail::variant::void_; T6 = boost::detail::variant::void_; T7 = boost::detail::variant::void_; T8 = boost::detail::variant::void_; T9 = boost::detail::variant::void_; T10 = boost::detail::variant::void_; T11 = boost::detail::variant::void_; T12 = boost::detail::variant::void_; T13 = boost::detail::variant::void_; T14 = boost::detail::variant::void_; T15 = boost::detail::variant::void_; T16 = boost::detail::variant::void_; T17 = boost::detail::variant::void_; T18 = boost::detail::variant::void_; T19 = boost::detail::variant::void_; typename Visitor::result_type = A::C<2ul>*]'
/usr/include/boost/variant/variant.hpp:2401:52:   required from 'typename Visitor::result_type boost::variant<T0, T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8, T9, T10, T11, T12, T13, T14, T15, T16, T17, T18, T19>::apply_visitor(Visitor&) [with Visitor = const A::C<2ul>; T0_ = A::C<2ul>*; T1 = A::C<1ul>*; T2 = boost::detail::variant::void_; T3 = boost::detail::variant::void_; T4 = boost::detail::variant::void_; T5 = boost::detail::variant::void_; T6 = boost::detail::variant::void_; T7 = boost::detail::variant::void_; T8 = boost::detail::variant::void_; T9 = boost::detail::variant::void_; T10 = boost::detail::variant::void_; T11 = boost::detail::variant::void_; T12 = boost::detail::variant::void_; T13 = boost::detail::variant::void_; T14 = boost::detail::variant::void_; T15 = boost::detail::variant::void_; T16 = boost::detail::variant::void_; T17 = boost::detail::variant::void_; T18 = boost::detail::variant::void_; T19 = boost::detail::variant::void_; typename Visitor::result_type = A::C<2ul>*]'
/usr/include/boost/variant/detail/apply_visitor_unary.hpp:76:43:   required from 'typename Visitor::result_type boost::apply_visitor(const Visitor&, Visitable&) [with Visitor = A::C<2ul>; Visitable = boost::variant<A::C<2ul>*, A::C<1ul>*>; typename Visitor::result_type = A::C<2ul>*]'
34:51:   required from here
/usr/include/boost/variant/variant.hpp:1048:32: error: cannot convert 'A::C<1ul>*' to 'boost::detail::variant::invoke_visitor<const A::C<2ul> >::result_type {aka A::C<2ul>*}' in return
         return visitor_(operand);
```

It compiles and works fine if I remove C<1> * from the boost::variant declaration.

Any suggestions would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All visitor functions must follow the scheme defined by base class:  `boost::static_visitor<C<dim> *>`.

That means return value of `operator()` must be always `C<dim> *` not `C<t>*` - see:

```
template<size_t dim>
struct C : boost::static_visitor<C<dim> *> {

   template <size_t t>
    C<dim> * operator()(C<t> *s) const {
  //  ^^^ - not t, must be as static_visitor parameter few lines above
      std::cout<<s->x<<std::endl;
      return s; // of course this part will have problems to compile
                // e.g. pointers to C<2> and C<1> are not convertible
    }
```

---

As I put in comments in right of `return s`- this does not compile - because compiler cannot covert `C<1>` to `C<2>`.

What you might do to solve this, is to introduce base class - like below:

```
struct CBase {
   int x;
};

template<size_t dim>
struct C : CBase, boost::static_visitor<CBase*> {

   C() : CBase{dim} {}

   template <size_t t>
    CBase* operator()(C<t> *s) const {
      std::cout<<s->x<<std::endl;
      return s; 
    }
```

Comment: I am trying to create a heterogeneous map of template objects using boost::variant. I wanted to understand how to use the static_visitor to get a pointer to the objects and so I used it within the constructor. Both, t and dim are still size_t objects and so it should not be any different?. However, it still throws the same error. Specifically, the following error is confusing to me. 21:22:  error: cannot convert 'A::C<1ul>*' to 'A::C<2ul>*' in return
 In member function 'A::C<dim>* A::C<dim>::operator()(A::C<t>*) const [with long unsigned int t = 1ul; long unsigned int dim = 2ul]':

Comment: see comment I put right of `return s;`. If you change this to `return nullptr;` you won't have any errors. However I bet this is not what you want... Just try to remember that `C<1>` and `C<2>` are not in any way related types - the fact that both are instantions of the same class template does not change this fact...

Comment: But you might relate `C<1>` and `C<2>` by introducing base class - like CBase - and use `CBase*` as return value of your operator and parameter to `boost::static_visitor`- that should work

Comment: That works! Thank you. Now, since I have a base class pointer I have to do a type case to access x, like, static_cast<C<2>*>(boost::apply_visitor(C<2>(), matrices["Bb"]))->x. I would like to access the member variables without knowing the types.

Comment: So, the idea is to access the x variable (This will be a Eigen matrix of templated size) through either of the pointers, Aasd or Bbsd from outside the class using something like ObjA[input]. "input" is a string variable that holds "Aa" or "Bb" accordingly. Since it is going to be a heterogeneous map, I thought of overloading the "[]" operator and giving access to either of the pointers based on the input string. Any thoughts or ideas?

Comment: It could work as you described for heterogeneous containers. But consider to put into base class all operations that are common  - so you wouldn't need to downcast. It is not always possible - but it is more "object oriented" way... You could also consider to use visitor or double-dispatch design pattern...